# How to create a grouped dot plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create grouped geom_point plots. Here is what I can do so far

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins
#> # A tibble: 344 × 8
#>    species island    bill_length_mm bill_depth_mm flipper_…¹ body_…² sex    year
#>    <fct>   <fct>              <dbl>         <dbl>      <int>   <int> <fct> <int>
#>  1 Adelie  Torgersen           39.1          18.7        181    3750 male   2007
#>  2 Adelie  Torgersen           39.5          17.4        186    3800 fema…  2007
#>  3 Adelie  Torgersen           40.3          18          195    3250 fema…  2007
#>  4 Adelie  Torgersen           NA            NA           NA      NA <NA>   2007

#> # … with 334 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​flipper_length_mm,
#> #   ²​body_mass_g
penguins %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(species,bill_length_mm, color=sex), 
              size = 3,
              alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange","purple"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

...**and here is** what I want to achieve.

- At first I want to be able to write code and have grouped dot plot based on the sex.
- In addition I want to show the mean and the sd for all the species.

Note: Here I am showing only the first species, because it would take me ages to change it and modify it by hand.

[image]

In addition, I want to be able to achieve having a more complex x a-axis, where I can indicate both male and female. I am only asking for didactic reasons so I can learn. Thank you community for your time

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a grouped dot plot add `position = position_jitterdodge` to `geom_jitter` so that the dots get dodged by `sex`. To add the mean and the standard deviation you could use `stat_summary` with `fun.data="mean_sdl`". By default this will give you an interval of +/- 2 times the standard deviation around the mean so I have set `mult=1` for just one sd:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(species, bill_length_mm, group = sex)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = sex),
    size = 3,
    alpha = 0.8,
    position = position_jitterdodge()
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1), #
    position = position_dodge(width = .75)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange", "purple"))
```

[image]

**EDIT** To put the `sex` on the axis map `sex` on `x` and facet by `species`. If desired you could get rid of the facet look using `theme` options, i.e. remove the space between the panels and the `strip.background`:

```r
penguins %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(sex, bill_length_mm, group = sex)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = sex),
    size = 3,
    alpha = 0.8
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange", "purple")) +
  facet_wrap(~species, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(color = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: my apologies stefan, is there an equally smart way to take the name "male and female" on bottom.  I do not really need but its more of a learning process for me.

Comment: You want them as axis labels? Or only move the legend to the bottom?

Comment: I want them as axis labels, as in the third plot in my question.

Comment: Actually that is a bit tricky but see my edit for one approach.